# How can one replicate a graph database like Neo4J

Tags: nosql, neo4j

I am noob in NoSQL world. but After going thru the basics of how Neo4J works, I didnt unerstand how will replication be fast compared to column or document databases or a plain key value DB.

It has nodes and edges which are nothing but relations between those nodes, something simiar to Joins in a RDBMS.

So how does replication works here as ccompared to an RDBMS ?

Comment: Can you post this comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each NoSQL database will behave in different ways when it comes to replication. NoSQL is quite a wide term, so you should not expect to have good replication performance for all of them. In fact Neo4j Enterprise has some support for replication, but the design of Neo4j does not naturally lead to scaling. It is certainly not of of the core objectives, unlike others like Cassandra for example.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with replication? Neo4j enterprise comes with an high-availability cluster that replicates your data across a number of machines.

If it is just about replicating the data, you can also shutdown your database and copy the database files (or in enterprise execute a online backup).